# Capturing aerial night photos during plane takeoff

Tags: lightroom, night-photography, aerial-photography

asking for CCs please. Raw picture and edited one using Lightroom.  Fujifilm XT-100, 15-45 mm, 15mm, f/3.5, 1/125, 6400. Took it while takeoff.  I only got 1/125 shutter speed to capture as much trade-off between exposure and detail. Any suggestions? Thank you! :)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SIIvh-59bgfPpH0M0GukpmOAs6Mj9FBL/view?usp=drivesdk

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SFgPIeHU7cc53TfEHQqTANDOomu6vuVJ/view?usp=drivesdk

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are "CCs" when you say you're asking for CCs?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't upload the photos from my mobile. I tried Googling but nothing works. Any suggestions?

Comment: Added Google Drive links with link sharing enabled. Hope you can see the pictures now.

Comment: I wouldn't, Scott. Please feel free to do so.

Comment: @scottbb, I think OP is using CC for ["constructive criticism", or "creative critique"](https://www.diyphotography.net/stop-asking-constructive-criticism-solicit-good-critique/).

Comment: @inkista Ah, that makes sense.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that you weren't able to do with this shot? It's hard for us to tell you how to "fix" something when we don't know what you think is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there's much you can do. The airplane is moving so you have to keep shutter speed up, and theres not much light to work with. Only thing you could do is upgrade your equipment. Go buy a fast lens like an f/1.8 or faster.

Comment: You'll need an aspherical fast lens to deal well with this kind of image (point light sources and extreme contrast) wide open. Nikon 35mm/f1.8 DX G or 50mm/f1.8 G (not the f1.4 versions here, they are spherical!) could work adapted. As would some of the expensive Sigma primes. Or various astro-proven wideangles (which would also allow you to lower shutter speed a bit!). The key is using a lens that has coma and oblique spherical aberration in check wide open - most vintage and/or inexpensive f1.4 or f1.8 lenses DO NOT.